# Check if pid of current page is X

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

How can I check if a page has a specific ID, and if true output a text?

I thought about something like this (pseudocode):

```
<f:if condition="{current.page.uid}=='78'">
    <p>I am Page 78</p>
</f:if>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to use this in an FLUIDTEMPLATE (`page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE` as example) you can access the page data with `{data.uid}`.

```
<f:if condition="{data.uid} == 78">
  <p>I am Page 78</p>
</f:if>
```

In an extbase Extension you can make it like @dimitri-l says.

Comment: It's `FLUIDTEMPLATE` without an underscore.

Answer (score 6):

You can fetch current page ID via typoscript object

typoscript:

```
lib.currentPageId = TEXT
lib.currentPageId.data = TSFE:id
```

FLUID:

```
<f:if condition="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.currentPageId')}==78">
    <p>I am Page 78</p>
</f:if>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a variable into your "page TS setup" like here :

```
variables {
    pageUid = TEXT
    pageUid.field = uid
    ...
}
```

So you can make your fluid condition as here :

```
<f:if condition="{pageUid}=={settings.homepid}">
    <p>I am Page 78</p>
</f:if>
```

for exemple...

Answer (score 2):

You would need to pass the page id to the fluid template. If you are using an Extbase controller you can pass `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->id` to your view and then use an if condition as you did.

```
$this->view->assign('pageId', $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id);
```

I am not sure if it is already possible to do string comparison in Typo3 6.2, if not, you have to compare it that way:

```
<f:if condition="{0:pageId} == {0:'78'}>
...
</f:if>
```

Otherwise this is a clean solution for current versions

```
<f:if condition="{pageId} == '78'>
...
</f:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the VHS viewhelper you can do it with fluid only, no need for a Typoscript helper:

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}

<f:if condition="{v:page.info(field: 'uid')} == '21'">
    <f:then>
        Shows only if page ID equals 21.
    </f:then>
</f:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to give a link a class when the link target is the current page (here: uid=1). The inline version helps:

```
<f:link.page pageUid="1"
        class="{f:if(condition: '{data.uid} == 1', then: ' current')}">
           Link
</f:link.page>
```